# Properties of the products of styrene chlorification

Tags: organic-chemistry, ethers

**Background:** When chlorinating styrene with an electrophile two products can be formed by substitution of the benzene ring. That is because the ethylene group is ortho and para directing, from the +M and the ± effect.

**Questions:** Which is the more stable product? Is the difference in stability related to the steric repulsion between the neighbouring groups in the ortho (1,2) product?

Also does the combination of the aromatic system and the vinyl group have any effect or interaction?